# Como mudar a raiz do meu site, sendo que a pasta está em um nível acima?

Tags: htaccess

A minha dúvida está no escalonamento do `.htaccess`, porquanto só consigo fazer com que a raiz do meu site seja a pasta `public_html` ou alguma outra pasta dentro de `public_html`, mas preciso de uma pasta que está um nível acima.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.meusite.com.br/$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.meusite.com.br/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !meudiretorio/
RewriteRule (.*) /meudiretorio/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sendo seu diretório `/var/www/public_html`, você precisa acessar `/var/www/outra_pasta`?

Comment: Exatamente, eu quero que minha pasta raiz seja outra.

Answer (score 1):

Isso não é feito no `.htaccess`.

Você deve alterar a configuração do Apache, no httpd.conf. Veja [DocumentRoot](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot).

Comment: Entendi, porém o caminho que está na documentação está diferente e não consigo achar esse arquivo.
Tem algum lugar no cPanel que eu consiga alterar o arquivo?

Comment: Veja se este link te ajuda https://support.hostgator.com/articles/what-is-a-document-root-folder

Comment: Ainda não consegui localizar, o documento só me mostra como fazer essa alteração em subdomínios, mas quando é no domínio primário não acho a informação.

Comment: Aqui tem informações para alterar do domínio primário. Faz tempo que não trabalho com CPANEL então não sei orientar melhor. Mas por qual motivo precisa alterar o documentroot do domínio primário?